# Issues with WAMP server after installing OSGeo4W

Tags: php, apache, osgeo

I recently downloaded WAMP server to get started developing a website locally on my Windows 7 32 bit computer. It was working fine.

Not long after, I downloaded a few different OSGeo4W packages mainly to use QGIS and develop plugins. This is when I began having issues accessing the phpmyadmin local host (page not found error).

I tried uninstalling WAMP in order to re-install it, and now it seems to be taking a very long time to extract files, blocking on the apache 2.4.9 files. Does anyone have any idea if this may be because OSGeo4 installed another version of Apache on my computer? How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is because apache is already running via OSGeo4W application. You can turn it off by launching OSGeo4W-Apache-Monitor and stopping the services. (start/all programs/Apache/OSGEO4W-Apache-Monitor.
Then restart wamp and it should work fine.